# 2 questions: A way to make an element fill the whole container of its grandparent? A way to prevent align-content from shrinking padding?

Tags: html, css, navigation, grid

I'm new to HTML & CSS and am creating webpages to put what I've learned into practice. I'm presently struggling with two issues.

I've created a Navbar (within a  container) with a dropdown attached to one of the  tags. To create the dropdown I had to wrap  around that  tag. This has resulted in the padding around that  tag being much smaller than the padding for the  tags outside the  container but within the  container. You can see this based on the borders in the pictures I've attached. Is it possible to make that  tag uniform with the others?

My second question concerns the use of the align-content property. I created a grid within the navbar and noticed that the padding for the  tags shrinks when I apply the align-content property. Again this is reflected by the borders in the pictures. Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

```
<nav class="main-nav-grid" style="grid-areas: 1 / 2 / span 1 / span 1">
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true" style="grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1"></i> Home</a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true" style="grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 1 / span 1"></i> About Us</a>
    <div class="dropdown" style="grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 1 / span 1">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i> Language</a>
      <nav class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">HTML</a>
        <a href="#">CSS</a>
        <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        <a href="#">Python</a>
        <a href="#">SQL</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" style="grid-area: 1 / 4 / span 1 / span 1"></i> Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
```

Navbar (no align-content):
[image: Navbar (no align-content)]

Navbar (align-content):
[image: Navbar (align-content)]

Comment: Can you paste your HTML and CSS into jsfiddle, then Save it, then post the link here?

Comment: Please add your css too.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d5nLfbq2/1/#&togetherjs=rdtkU7D54B

Comment: Sorry, having trouble adding the CSS side. But I have uploaded it to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You just need two changes to achieve this:

Within `.main-nav-grid a:hover` change `font-weight: 900;` to be `font-weight: 600;`. The effect of this is that it doesn't resize the boxes, so we won't have layout problems later.

Add this at the end of the CSS:

```css
.dropdown > a {
    display: block;
}
```

That will make the `Language` `a` fill the `dropdown` div. That makes it match the other links.

End result: https://jsfiddle.net/ao028Lwe/

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there anyway to centre the content vertically without shrinking the border? I've edited out the align-content: center to show you what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/va6z73mp/1/#&togetherjs=hoihoRth7t

Comment: Yeah, you can achieve that by setting the line-height of the elements to same height as the container (minus one pixel to account for the border): https://jsfiddle.net/s8a4wqLr/

Comment: Thanks for all the help. That worked as well.